# How can I use a register with :find?

Tags: normal-mode, register, functions, variables

I'm trying to improve my vim-abilities. I'm writing a command and a function to find the current **W**ord under the cursor. What I want to be able to do is type `:FindFile` and have the word under the current cursor open.

```
" Find the file under the current W word.
function! FindFile()
    let l:contents = @"
    normal viWy
    find l:contents
    set @" = l:contents
endfunction
command! FindFile :call FindFile()
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm still a n00b at vimscript, but I figured out the following.

```
function! FindFile()
    find <cWORD>
endfunction
```